# Removing unwanted elements from XML file using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a lot of XML files which have something of the form:

```
<param>
<name>hello</name>
<value>world</world>
</param>
```

Which I want to be removed from the file.

Using XSL how can I do this?

I found out that if i had the same in the format

```
<param name="hello" value="world"/>
```

then the following XSL will do the trick

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="param[@name='hello']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using java transfromer so any Java based solution will also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove elements in the format posted at the top of the question, you can simply change `match` attribute of the 2nd template to be as follow :

```
<xsl:template match="param[name='hello']"/>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform demo`](http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9s)</kbd>**

With the `@` character at the beginning removed, the expression now match `param` elements with `name` child element value equals `"hello"`.